# Question about Algebraic Spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have two questions about Knutson's Algebraic Spaces.

1. Can one clarify Prop 5.2 to me which says the following. Let $R\rightarrow U\times U$ be a categorical equivalence relation. Then there is a unique map $i:U\rightarrow R$ such that the composite $U\rightarrow R\rightarrow U\times U$ is the diagonal.
2. Can one clarify the second line of the proof of Prop 5.9 starting with "Then"? Assume we have maps of sheaves $V^{\cdot}\rightarrow U^{\cdot}\rightarrow F$. Why is it true that
   $V^{\cdot}\times_{F}U^{\cdot}=V^{\cdot}\times_{U^{\cdot}}U^{\cdot}\times U^{\cdot}=V^{\cdot}\times_{U^{\cdot}}R^{\cdot}$?

Comment: Can you at least type the Propositions in? Since probably not everyone has that book...

Comment: Another option is to scan the relevant pages in the book and attach an image.

Comment: Concerning 1., doesn't the uniqueness of $i$ follow immediately from the fact that $\delta$ is mono, and the existence of $i$ follows from reflexivity of the equivalence relation $R \subset U \times U$ (we have $(u,u) \in R$ for all $u \in U$)?

Comment: I still do not understand. I do not see that there is at all a map $U\rightarrow R$.

Comment: Now, I see 1. What about 2?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting and trying to close this question. Could someone explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused with local effectiveness of etale equivalence relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449521/confused-with-local-effectiveness-of-etale-equivalence-relations)

Comment: @ZhenLin: Dear Zhen, How is this possibly a duplicate?  Just looking at the words and notation occuring in the two questions should make it clear that they are not at all the same question. Regards,

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: I have no idea why this was closed.  It is a specific question from a specific book.   I have voted to reopen, and I hope others will too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help you (in understanding these and related questions) to apply Yoneda's lemma bit more conciously in your thinking.  Yoneda's lemma is pretty easy as a technical result, but incredibly powerful as a psychological tool!

For example, to say that $R$ is a categorical equivalence relation on $U$ is (unless I've got the definition wrong) to say that for any $X$ in the category,
the map $$Hom(X,R) \to Hom(X,U) \times Hom(X,U)$$ induced by the given map $R\to U\times U$ induces an equivalence relation on $Hom(X,U)$.

In particular, the diagonal $Hom(X,U)$ must be contained in $Hom(X,R)$.  This holds
for all $X$, so by Yoneda, the diagonal $U \to U\times U$ factors through $R$.

For the second point, I can't quite work out the context from what you've written, but it should follow from universal properties of fibre products (such as $(X \times_Z Y) \times _Y W = X \times_Z W\,$), and again Yoneda should help, i.e. you just have to check that the two expressions represent the same functor.

E.g. here is how you could verify the identity I wrote above:

Giving a map (from some $T$, say) to $(X \times_Z Y) \times_Y W$ is the same as giving maps
to $(X\times_Z Y)$ and to $W$ lying over the same map to $Y$, which is the
same as giving maps to $X$ and $Y$ lying over the same map to $Z$, and a map to $W$ lying over the given map to $Y$.

Since the map to $Y$ is determined by the map to $W$, we can forget it, and just think about the maps to $Z$; thus we just have to give a map to $X$ and $W$ lying over the same map to $W$.

(This is easier if you write down all the relevant maps with pen and paper!)

---

Here is something more specific about question (2):

First note that $R$ is equal to the fibre product $U \times_F U$ (it gives the equivalence relation modulo which morphisms to $U$ are being identified to give
rise to the quotient sheaf $F$).

So we get that $$V \times_F U = V \times_U (U\times_F U) = V\times_U R;$$
the first identification is the one already discussed in what I wrote earlier,
and the second comes from the fact I just mentioned.

Comment: I know that $(X\times_Z Y)\times_Y W$ is isomorphic to $X\times_Z W$. I do not see why it is relevant for my question.

Comment: @Marci: Dear Marci, I've never read Knutson's book, so I don't know what the precise statement is that you're asking about.  But it looks to be something similar (if slightly more involved) then my example --- namely, a manipulation with fibre products.  If that's not the case, then unfortunately I won't be able to say more unless you give a little more detail (since I'm not likely to get hold of Knutson's book anytime soon).  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, the only assumptions are the following. F is the categroical quotient (sheaf) of $R^{\cdot}\rightarrow U^{\cdot}\times U^{\cdot}$, where $X^{\cdot}$ denotes the sheaf $Hom(-,X)$. $V^{\cdot}\rightarrow F$ is any map of sheaves which factors through $U^{\cdot}$.

Comment: @Marci: Dear Marci, I amplified my answer based on the additional explanation.  The answer combines the associativity of fibre products that I already discussed, combined with the description of $R$ as a fibre product.  Regards,